# Kernel Panic in a linux kernel image that is running on a xilinx FPGA

Tags: fpga, xilinx

```
Early console on uartlite at 0x84000000
bootconsole [earlyser0] enabled
Ramdisk addr 0x00000000, 
Compiled-in FDT at 0xc035c060
Linux version 3.12.0 (mdt@linux-t5z7) (gcc version 4.6.4 20120924 (Xilinx 14.1 Build EDK_P.13 28 Sep 2013) (crosstool-NG 1.18.0) ) #61 Tue Jun 28 18:58:56 IST 2016
setup_cpuinfo: initialising
setup_cpuinfo: No PVR support. Using static CPU info from FDT
wt_msr
setup_memory: max_mapnr: 0x4000
setup_memory: min_low_pfn: 0x44000
setup_memory: max_low_pfn: 0x48000
setup_memory: max_pfn: 0x48000
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x44000000-0x47ffffff]
  Normal   empty
  HighMem  empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x44000000-0x47ffffff]
On node 0 totalpages: 16384
free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0477d1c, node_mem_map c05f2000
  DMA zone: 128 pages used for memmap
  DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
  DMA zone: 16384 pages, LIFO batch:3
early_printk_console remapping from 0x84000000 to 0xff7ff000
pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 16256
Kernel command line: console=ttyUL0,115200
PID hash table entries: 256 (order: -2, 1024 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Memory: 58768K/65536K available (3440K kernel code, 148K rwdata, 948K rodata, 938K init, 551K bss, 6768K reserved, 0K highmem)
Kernel virtual memory layout:
  * 0xfffea000..0xfffff000  : fixmap
  * 0xff800000..0xffc00000  : highmem PTEs
  * 0xff7ff000..0xff800000  : early ioremap
  * 0xf0000000..0xff7ff000  : vmalloc & ioremap
NR_IRQS:33
/plb@0/interrupt-controller@81800000: num_irq=4, edge=0xb
/plb@0/timer@83c00000: irq=1
xilinx_timer_set_mode: shutdown
xilinx_timer_set_mode: periodic
Calibrating delay loop... 30.10 BogoMIPS (lpj=150528)
pid_max: default: 4096 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
NET: Registered protocol family 16
PCI: Probing PCI hardware
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
vgaarb: loaded
Switched to clocksource xilinx_clocksource
NET: Registered protocol family 2
TCP established hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 10240 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 512 bind 512)
TCP: reno registered
UDP hash table entries: 128 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 128 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 32
gpiochip_find_base: cannot find free range
gpiochip_add: gpios -1..-2 (/plb@0/gpio@81440000) failed to register
/plb@0/gpio@81440000: GPIO chip registration failed with status -28
/plb@0/gpio@81440000: error in probe function with status -28
xilinx-gpio: probe of 81440000.gpio failed with error -28
gpiochip_find_base: cannot find free range
gpiochip_add: gpios -1..-2 (/plb@0/gpio@81420000) failed to register
/plb@0/gpio@81420000: GPIO chip registration failed with status -28
/plb@0/gpio@81420000: error in probe function with status -28
xilinx-gpio: probe of 81420000.gpio failed with error -28
gpiochip_find_base: cannot find free range
gpiochip_add: gpios -1..-2 (/plb@0/gpio@81400000) failed to register
/plb@0/gpio@81400000: GPIO chip registration failed with status -28
/plb@0/gpio@81400000: error in probe function with status -28
xilinx-gpio: probe of 81400000.gpio failed with error -28
Skipping unavailable RESET gpio -2 (reset)
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(10.250:1): initialized
ROMFS MTD (C) 2007 Red Hat, Inc.
msgmni has been set to 114
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
84000000.serial: ttyUL0 at MMIO 0x84000000 (irq = 4, base_baud = 0) is a uartlite
console [ttyUL0] enabled, bootconsole disabled
console [ttyUL0] enabled, bootconsole disabled
brd: module loaded
xilinx_emaclite 81000000.ethernet: Device Tree Probing
libphy: Xilinx Emaclite MDIO: probed
mdio_bus 81000000: cannot get PHY at address 7
xilinx_emaclite 81000000.ethernet: MAC address is now 00:0a:35:00:00:00
xilinx_emaclite 81000000.ethernet: Xilinx EmacLite at 0x81000000 mapped to 0xF00C0000, irq=3
PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
PPP BSD Compression module registered
PPP Deflate Compression module registered
NET: Registered protocol family 24
Oops: kernel access of bad area, sig: 11
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 3.12.0 #61
task: c382dbe0 ti: c382e000 task.ti: c382e000
 Registers dump: mode=4782FDB4
 r1=C30999C0, r2=00000000, r3=000061A2, r4=00000000
 r5=C0471A90, r6=C309CA00, r7=0000006F, r8=C0460420
 r9=00000000, r10=00000003, r11=00000000, r12=00000000
 r13=00000000, r14=C035B72C, r15=C025C5E0, r16=00000000
 r17=C025C628, r18=7FFFFF90, r19=00000011, r20=C0350384
 r21=00000000, r22=C04918A4, r23=000061A2, r24=00000007
 r25=00000000, r26=0000005D, r27=00000000, r28=00000000
 r29=00000000, r30=00000000, r31=C382DBE0, rPC=C025C628
 msr=000042A0, ear=00000064, esr=000002D2, fsr=00000000
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
```

** i cross compiled and downloaded a linux image to a xilinx FPGA and after opening a picocom terminal and running, the following kernel panic error was displayed.Please help me figure this out
Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel got a bad page fault for some reason. There is not really enough information here to say why.

The offending instruction was at PC=C025C628, which you might be able to find in the symbol table of your vmlinux.

Comment: did you look at System.map for your kernel? that would give you an idea which code is accessing an invalid address.